# "Stretching" dataset in python

Tags: python, statistics, dataset, pattern-matching

I have a dataset `t1` that I would like to stretch. As you can see below, it has a length of 9. Could I stretch it to a length of 30 without adding padding values. Ideally, the property of the datset (= for example how the values change) should be kept as much as possible. Could anyone give me some hint/advise?

```
t1=[106.7, 106.7, 99.94, 95.83, 92.84, 90.44, 88.3, 86.12, 82.22, 77.2]
plt.plot(range(0,len(t1)), t1)
plt.legend()
```

[image]

---

Dataset rescaled with zoom :
[image]

---

I took a different dataset and rescaled with mean:

```
t1= [144.8025, 144.3592, 143.6091, 142.5525, 141.1892, 139.5193, 137.5428, 135.2597, 132.6699, 129.7736, 126.5706, 123.061, 119.2447, 115.1218, 110.6924, 105.9563, 100.9135, 95.5642, 89.9082, 83.9456, 77.6764, 71.1005, 64.2181, 57.029, 49.5333, 41.7309, 33.622, 25.2064, 16.4842, 7.4554, 144.7695, 144.293, 143.5099, 142.4202, 141.0239, 139.3209, 137.3113, 134.9951, 132.3723, 129.4428, 126.2068, 122.6641, 118.8148, 114.6588, 110.1963, 105.4271, 100.3513, 94.9689, 89.2798, 83.2841, 76.9818, 70.3729, 63.4574, 56.2352, 48.7064, 40.871, 32.729, 24.2804, 15.5251, 6.4632, 141.1892, 139.5193, 137.5428, 135.2597, 132.6699, 129.7736, 126.5706, 123.061, 119.2447, 115.1218, 110.6924, 105.9563, 100.9135, 95.5642, 89.9082, 83.9456, 77.6764, 71.1005, 64.2181, 57.029, 49.5333, 41.7309, 33.622, 25.2064, 16.4842, 7.4554]
```

[image]

---

Above plot in seperated plot with fixed size `plt.figure(figsize=(12, 6))`

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you want to resample your array.

There are many ways to do this but my favorite is `zoom` from the `scipy` library:
https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.14.0/reference/generated/scipy.ndimage.interpolation.zoom.html

```
from scipy.ndimage.interpolation import zoom
import numpy as np

# original array:
x = np.array([106.7, 106.7, 99.94, 95.83, 92.84, 90.44, 88.3, 86.12, 82.22, 77.2])

# set resample ratio:
resample_ratio = 30 / len(x)

# resample array:
y = zoom(x, resample_ratio)
```

Comment: Thank you for the advise with "zoom". However, as you can see above, the property of the datasat has slightly changed. Around x=3, the plot goes up, whereas in the original dataset it is flat. How could I Prevent this?

Answer (score 0):

I tried to obtain the same curve but stretched for fun, without using fancy libraries. Basically I am doing the mean for every couple of points, till I reach 30 elements.
Btw it is better to use zoom.

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from numpy import mean

def stretch(list_):
    i = 0
    while len(list_) < 30:
        if i == len(list_)-1:
            i = 0
        curr_new_point = mean([list_[i], list_[i+1]])
        list_ = list_[:i+1] + [curr_new_point] + list_[i+1:]
        i+=2
    return list_


t1=[106.7, 106.7, 99.94, 95.83, 92.84, 90.44, 88.3, 86.12, 82.22, 77.2]
plt.plot(range(0, len(t1)), t1)
plt.legend()
plt.show()

stretched = stretch(t1)
plt.plot(range(0, len(stretched)), stretched)
plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

Comment: Yes, the approach seems to be more "stable", but again around x=60~70 the stretched dataset somehow looks different...

Comment: @joee you should not plot them together in the same plot, otherwise you will see them a lot different

Comment: no...either I plot them together or seperately the result is same.

Comment: @joee have you tried to fix the width size for both the plots?

Comment: Yes of course, but as you can see the stretched dataset Shows different shape at x= 60~70.

Comment: @joee I understand now. The problem of my method is that it does not increase equally the points. Try to set in the while the limit to 170(the double of 85, your dataset size) and you'll see that the plot are the almost the same. For my method you can increase the points only in multiples of the size of your dataset